# How to copy text files inside a .jar file when the .jar is executed

Tags: java, file, jar

I want to make modifications to a text file inside a .jar and hence instead of directly writing into a file in the .jar file thought of copying the files onto an external location and making modifications to that. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do that without extracting and re-jarring. Use the following command

> jar uf jar-file input-file(s)

In archive, files having same pathname as file being added would be overwritten.

As it is a file it is easy to modify and there would be no need to re-build the jar

See this reference for further details : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you tell me how can do this? go into the project location and enter the command? did not work.